# Чтение boot sector с разных дисков

Tags: ассемблер, ос

Я пробовал успешно написать загрузочные сектора для флоппи, и CD ROM, и меня интересует вопрос - почему при загрузки с FDD и HDD нужна таблица Bios Parameter Block, а в случае чтения загрузочного сектора с CD ROM данная таблица BPB в коде не требуется? Откуда Bios знает как читать CD ROM?

Comment: Может просто FDD и HDD бывают разных типов и их много, разное количество секторов, головок, прочее, а CDROM у него одна конструкция и устройство диска на все случаи жизни. Поэтому в BIOS функция int 13h -> 042h может читать CDROM, его устройство жестко закодировано в BIOS. Есть какие то мысли у кого- то может?